# Save Sparql results into virtuoso conductor

Tags: save, sparql, virtuoso

I want to save results of a Sparql query :

```
SELECT ?items ?head 
FROM <http://localhost:8890/diplomatiki#>
WHERE {
?exeiId <http://localhost:8890/schemas/diplomatiki/itemid> ?items;
             <http://localhost:8890/schemas/diplomatiki/headid> ?head
}
```

into a table or as a linked Data locally (virtuoso conductor), How can Ι do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create your own procedure.

like:

```
create procedure
INSERT_SPARQL_RESULT
(
in query VARCHAR
)
{
DECLARE state, msg, descs, rows any;
exec('SPARQL ' || query, state, msg, vector (), 0, descs, rows);

declare i INTEGER;
for(i:=0;i<LENGTH(rows);i:=i+1){
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (rows[i][0], rows[i][1]);
}
};
```

It is important to add 'SPARQL ' before your query.

After successfully creating your procedure:

```
CALL INSERT_SPARQL_RESULT('
SELECT ?items ?head 
FROM <http://localhost:8890/diplomatiki#>
WHERE {
?exeiId <http://localhost:8890/schemas/diplomatiki/itemid> ?items;
             <http://localhost:8890/schemas/diplomatiki/headid> ?head
}');
```